# 2007 VW Touareg V6 TDI BKS engine query on normal EGT values on idle and load

Tags: vw, sensor

I have a 2007 VW Touareg 3.0 TDI, BKS engine whose Exhaust Gas Temperature values (Read under Measuring Value Blocks 102.1 and 102.2) are as follows:

1. 102.1 fixed at a constant 551.0C
2. 102.2 fixed at a constant -53.1C

Regardless of running conditions, be it at idle, engine off with consumer electrics ON or on the road. These values do not change.

Is this normal behavior, or should I have the exhaust temperature sensor G235 inspected and / or changed?

Note that my machine has the DPF gutted and deleted from the ECU mapping, and the DPF sensor(s) all removed.

Any pointers?

Comment: I don't know enough about these systems to answer the question, but I'm wondering if what you're reading is actually the max and min values which *these could be* and not what the system is seeing. It seems to me if the EGT's were beyond either of these values the system might throw a code. If that isn't the case and you're reading things correctly, then there is most likely a problem with the sensor itself.

Comment: Hello @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 this is what I get via both VCDS and Diagzone Pro's diagnostics when I query the aforementioned Measuring Value Blocks (MVBs). The EGT appears "stuck" to these values and they don't update. Need to confirm if this is indeed normal.

Comment: Another point which leads me to what I'm saying is, if you are looking at the actual EGT value, you'd be looking at one cell, not two.